# Error: Value for argument 'data' is not a valid Firestore document. Cannot use 'undefined'; as a Firestore value

Tags: javascript, authentication, stack, mern

I am new to MERN stack and just started working in Node and creating Login SignUp services

This is the tutorial I am following https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=m_u6P5k0vP0

I reached at 1:30 Hrs:Mins

When I am trying to post a scream using POST request after logging in using POSTMAN and having tokenId generated and passed in header of scream POST request the following error returned in postman

```
**<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Error</title>
</head>
<body>
    <pre>Error: Value for argument &quot;data&quot; is not a valid Firestore document. Cannot use &quot;undefined&quot; as a Firestore value (found in field &quot;userHandle&quot;). If you want to ignore undefined values, enable `ignoreUndefinedProperties`.<br> &nbsp; &nbsp;at validateUserInput (/Users/raza/Desktop/socialape-functions/functions/node_modules/@google-cloud/firestore/build/src/serializer.js:268:19)<br> &nbsp; &nbsp;at Object.validateUserInput (/Users/raza/Desktop/socialape-functions/functions/node_modules/@google-cloud/firestore/build/src/serializer.js:260:13)<br> &nbsp; &nbsp;at Object.validateDocumentData (/Users/raza/Desktop/socialape-functions/functions/node_modules/@google-cloud/firestore/build/src/write-batch.js:641:18)<br> &nbsp; &nbsp;at CollectionReference.add (/Users/raza/Desktop/socialape-functions/functions/node_modules/@google-cloud/firestore/build/src/reference.js:2008:23)<br> &nbsp; &nbsp;at /Users/raza/Desktop/socialape-functions/functions/index.js:95:6<br> &nbsp; &nbsp;at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/Users/raza/Desktop/socialape-functions/functions/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)<br> &nbsp; &nbsp;at next (/Users/raza/Desktop/socialape-functions/functions/node_modules/express/lib/router/route.js:137:13)<br> &nbsp; &nbsp;at /Users/raza/Desktop/socialape-functions/functions/index.js:66:12<br> &nbsp; &nbsp;at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:97:5)</pre>
</body>
</html>**
```

This is my index.js file

```
const functions = require("firebase-functions");
const admin = require("firebase-admin");
const app = require("express")();
admin.initializeApp();
const firebaseConfig = {
  apiKey: "AIzaSyBSWcDkgu4PHvCxeNHXbdW8l00by4SdUXM",
  authDomain: "socialape-7830c.firebaseapp.com",
  databaseURL: "https://socialape-7830c.firebaseio.com",
  projectId: "socialape-7830c",
  storageBucket: "socialape-7830c.appspot.com",
  messagingSenderId: "960517598821",
  appId: "1:960517598821:web:a53cc5ca90a3f56853e08c",
  measurementId: "G-7MNYCPGQL6",
};
const firebase = require("firebase");
const e = require("express");
firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
const db = admin.firestore();
//usman question about data.....can data and doc both be any variable names
//Screams GET req
app.get("/screams", (req, res) => { 
  db.collection("screams")
    .orderBy("createdAt", "desc")
    .get()
    .then((data) => {
      let screams = [];
      data.forEach((doc) => {
        screams.push({
          screamId: doc.id,
          body: doc.data().body,
          userHandle: doc.data().userHandle,
          createdAt: doc.data().createdAt,
        });
      });
      return res.json(screams);
    })
    .catch((err) => console.error(err));
});
const middleWareAuth = (req, res, next) => {
  let idToken;
  if(req.headers.authorization && req.headers.authorization.startsWith('Bearer ')){
    idToken = req.headers.authorization.split('Bearer ')[1];
  }else {
    console.error('No token found');
    return res.status(403).json({error: 'Unauthorized due to no authorization header token'});
  }
  admin.auth().verifyIdToken(idToken)
  .then(decodedToken => {
    req.user = decodedToken;
    console.log(decodedToken);
    return db.collection('users')
     .where('userId', '==', req.user.uid)
     .limit(1)
     .get();
  })
  .then(data => {
    req.user.handle = data.docs[0].data().hanlde;
    return next();
  })
  .catch(err => {
    console.error('Error while verifying token ', err);
    return res.status(403).json(err);
  })
}
//POST one scream
//later on adding middleware authentication as a 2nd argument in ".post('route', 2nd argument, (req,res))" for ...
app.post("/scream", middleWareAuth, (req, res) => {
  console.log("req check",req);
  if (req.body.body.trim() === "") {
    return res.status(400).json({ body: "Body must not be empty" });
  }
  // const newScream = {
  //   body: req.body.body,
  //   userHandle: req.user.handle,
  //   createdAt: new Date().toISOString()
  // };
  const newScream = {
    body: req.body.body,
    userHandle: req.user.handle,
    createdAt: new Date().toISOString(),
  };
  db.collection("screams")
    .add(newScream)
    .then((doc) => {
      res.json({ message: `document ${doc.id} created successfully` });
    })
    .catch((err) => {
      res.status(501).json({ error: "Something went wrong" });
      console.error(err);
    });
});
//Helper function to check email is not empty
const isEmpty = (string) => {
  if (string.trim() === "") return true;
  else return false;
};
//Helper function to check if the email is valid
const isEmailValid = (email) => {
  const regEx = /^\w+([\.-]?\w+)*@\w+([\.-]?\w+)*(\.\w{2,3})+$/;
  if (email.match(regEx)) return true;
  else return false;
};
//Sign Up route
app.post("/signup", (req, res) => {
  const newUser = {
    email: req.body.email,
    password: req.body.password,
    confirmPassword: req.body.confirmPassword,
    handle: req.body.handle,
  };
  let errors = {};
  if (isEmpty(newUser.email)) {
    errors.email = "Must not be empty";
  } else if (!isEmailValid(newUser.email)) {
    errors.email = "Must be a valid email address";
  }
  //Validation for password and confirmPassword
  if (isEmpty(newUser.password)) errors.password = "Must not be empty";
  if (newUser.password !== newUser.confirmPassword)
    errors.confirmPassword = "Passwords must match";
  if (isEmpty(newUser.handle)) errors.handle = "Must not be empty";
  //Now checking the errors Object if its empty means no validation error if it has any key in it
  //means there is an validation error so lets check
  if (Object.keys(errors).length > 0) return res.status(400).json(errors);
  //TODO: validate data
  let token, userId;
  db.doc(`/users/${newUser.handle}`)
    .get()
    .then((doc) => {
      if (doc.exists) {
        return res.status(400).json({ handle: "This handle is already taken" });
      } else {
        return firebase
          .auth()
          .createUserWithEmailAndPassword(newUser.email, newUser.password);
      }
    })
    .then((data) => {
      userId = data.user.uid;
      return data.user.getIdToken();
    })
    .then((idToken) => {
      token = idToken;
      const userCredentials = {
        handle: newUser.handle,
        email: newUser.email,
        createdAt: new Date().toISOString(),
        userId,
      };
      return db.doc(`/users/${newUser.handle}`).set(userCredentials);
    })
    .then(() => {
      return res.status(201).json({ token });
    })
    .catch((err) => {
      console.error(err);
      if (err.code === "auth/email-already-in-use") {
        return res.status(400).json({ error: "Email is already in use" });
      } else {
        return res.status(500).json({ error: err.code });
      }
    });
});
//Login route
app.post("/login", (req, res) => {
  const user = {
    email: req.body.email,
    password: req.body.password,
  };
  //errors empty object
  let errors = {};
  if (isEmpty(user.email)) errors.email = "Must not be empty";
  if (isEmpty(user.password)) errors.password = "Must not be empty";
  if (Object.keys(errors).length > 0) return res.status(400).json(errors);
  firebase
    .auth()
    .signInWithEmailAndPassword(user.email, user.password)
    .then((data) => {
      return data.user.getIdToken();
    })
    .then((token) => {
      return res.json({ token });
    })
    .catch((err) => {
      console.error(err);
      if (err.code === "auth/wrong-password") {
        return res
          .status(401)
          .json({ general: "Wrong credentials, please try again" });
      } else return res.status(500).json({ error: err.code });
    });
});
//www.baseurl.com/api/screams
exports.api = functions.https.onRequest(app);
```

This is my package.json file

```
**{
  "name": "functions",
  "description": "Cloud Functions for Firebase",
  "scripts": {
    "serve": "firebase emulators:start --only functions",
    "shell": "firebase functions:shell",
    "start": "npm run shell",
    "deploy": "firebase deploy --only functions",
    "logs": "firebase functions:log"
  },
  "engines": {
    "node": "8"
  },
  "main": "index.js",
  "dependencies": {
    "express": "^4.17.1",
    "firebase": "^7.19.1",
    "firebase-admin": "^8.10.0",
    "firebase-functions": "^3.6.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "firebase-functions-test": "^0.2.0"
  },
  "private": true
}**
```

Any help will be highly appreciated please let me know if you need any more info

I am using Cloud FireStore DB of Google Firebase.

Regards
Syed Hassan Raza

Answer (score 1):

The problem has been resolved. Its because of DB as in code the index for docs[0] and I have multiple users in DB which were causing the issue. Hence the issue got resolved when I deleted all other users except the req one.

Answer (score 0):

at this line

userHandle: req.user.handle

of newScream json object the req.user.handle is returning an undefined value which causing the issue.